# Import python modules in separate script

Tags: python, import, python-import, project-structure, relative-import

Similar questions have been asked many times, but I didn't find a solution yet. I have Python Project that is structured as follows (simplified version).
The problem is to import `module1` in `myscript.py`.
So far, I've written `sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), '..'))` on top of `myscript.py`, but this is not very elegant and I wonder what's the best structure for my project that can easily import modules from the project to scripts that are located in a separate folder.

```
project
--project
----module1.py
----module2.py
----__init__.py
--examples
--scripts
---myscript.py
--Readme.md
```

Comment: you can look at this link http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/
also there is a PEP that is describing how to organize a project (don't remember wich one exactly)

Comment: What's the purpose of `myscript.py`? For testing the other modules? An example of using them, or?

Comment: No, the scripts (actually there's at least a dozen) contain measurements, evaluations and other stuff using the modules of the project.